# PHP-FPM on nginx will not connect to an external MySQL

Tags: mysql, nginx, php

I have a centos server running nginx + php-fpm that will not connect to an external database for the purpose of a wordpress install.

I can ssh into the webs erver and run mysql to connect to the external mysql database fine but when trying to us php to connect to the database it fails.

Where should I look to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check your php logs as well as your nginx logs (in CentOS, these are usually at /var/log unless you changed the paths).  Chances are, you have a permission issue.  It may also be useful to see your configuration files if you can't get the answer from the logs.

Comment: First of all you should ask on the appropriate site, i.e. serverfault, Unix, ... that kind of problem may be based on tons of reasons: ACL on mysql server, firewall on 3306, name resolution, user rights, network problems, etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the problem to be related to selinux (as it was in my case today).

Try to run

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: If OP can connect locally it's unlikely a selinux problem.

Comment: @ringø I've had the same issue today. I could connect locally, but not to any remote mysql server. The issue was finally solved by the command above. (centos 6)